# SQLITE select only numeric values from text field

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, select

In VB .net I'm wanting to run an sqlite select statement to fetch only numeric values from a text field (a4) which contains both numbers and letters.

My sqlite text a4 field data contains data like this:

```
  28 days
  1966
  the 100 years war
```

In would like to be able to fetch

```
  28
  1966
  100
```

The sqlite a4 field has a text data type

This is what I have tried

```
SELECT a4 from data where CAST(a4 AS INTEGER) GLOB '[0-9]'
SELECT a4 FROM data WHERE a4 REGEXP '[0-9]'
```

I have search for an answer but only found MS SQL answer that uses ISNUMERIC which doesn't exist in SQLITE.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe in the close but no cigar category: `trim(lower(info),"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ")`. I guess you could include special characters too. But it wouldn't work on `2 plus 2 is 4` for instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in SQL for SQLite3:

```
SELECT ROUND(a4) from data WHERE NOT ROUND(a4) = 0;
```

This is because non-numeric values applied to the ROUND() function result in a value of 0. For example:

```
sqlite> select round('hello');
round('hello')
--------------
0.0
```

..whereas numeric values stored as text become numbers:

```
sqlite> select round('1234');
round('1234')
-------------
1234.0
```

**N.B. There is a limitation to this solution is if a numeric value is also '0' or rounds to 0.0, such as text value '0.1'. It also will give a false positive if the text starts with a number but includes other characters, e.g.**

```
sqlite> select round('1234Hello');
round('1234Hello')
------------------
1234.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Not done in the database but in the client code.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim strings() As String = {"28 days", "1966", "the 100 years war"}
    Dim numbers As New List(Of String)
    For Each s In strings
        Dim num As String = ""
        For Each c As Char In s
            If Char.IsNumber(c) Then
                num &= c
            End If
        Next
        numbers.Add(num)
    Next
    For Each num In numbers
        Debug.Print(num)
    Next
    '28
    '1966
    '100
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary, I might have to revert to this if I cannot achieve something similar using sql.